# Match multiple whole words with regex with php

Tags: php, regex

I'm implementing a "Tags" feature in our custom product management system. Each product has a comma seperated list of tags associated. We have a "tag search" with check boxes. The user can check multiple tags and it will filter with ajax with all the selected tags, so all tags need to be matched together. Example.

```
Tags: Tag1,Tag2,Tag3

#1-product-tags: Tag3,Tag10,Tag2
#2-product-tags: Tag1,Tag3,Tag10
#3-product-tags: Tag5,Tag1,Tag3
#4-product-tags: Tag8,Tag4,Tag20
#5-product-tags: Tag20,Tag100,Tag500
```

When filtering with the above tags checked, I expect to return #1,#2,#3 only because the given tags are listed in the product-tags column of these products.

Im currently trying to use regular expressions by dynamically creating a regex when the user checks the tags. In order to qualify as a match, the product must have all tags checked. Im generating this like so:

```
   <?php 
       //empty collection array to fill with product loop
       $collection = array();

       //dynamically generated regex
       $regex = "\b" . $tag1 . "|" . $tag2 . "|" . $tag3 . "\b/i";

       //loop through each product and throw matches to collection
       foreach($products as $product) {
         if(preg_match($regex,$product->tags)) {
            array_push($collection,$product);
         }
       }
    ?>
```

I am not getting the expected result doing it this way. What is the best way I can get my expected result. Im not too great with Regular Expressions but I am learning.

Comment: I'm assuming the product tags/columns are in an array? And You are missing the beginning delimiter of your regex.

Comment: all tags are a string on a column per product. so each product has a column "tags" and they are a comma separated string.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what \b is in regex, but I believe your expression should begin with a delimiter (/ is used at the end, but not the beginning). `$regex = "/\b" . $tag1 ... . "\b/i"`

Comment: Im not sure exactly, but from what I read \b would surround a whole word so the entire word matches and not just a part of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the tags are stored in an array as comma-separated strings. If that's the case, you can split them into individual arrays using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and then loop through the array and use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to see if any of the sub-arrays have **all** the values in the `$search` array:

```
$search = ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3'];

$taglist = array_map(function ($v) { return explode(',', $v); }, $tags);

foreach ($taglist as $sub) {
    if (count(array_intersect($sub, $search)) == count($search)) {
        $products[] = implode(',', $sub);
    }
}
```

Not only this approach is efficient, it is more flexible. It will not be a problem if you have multiple conditions to check for. If you were to do this with a regex, you'd have a hard time crafting the regex and chances are it will be a lot slower than this simple split & loop solution.

For the tags in the question, this would return nothing — `$products` array would be empty.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/LrxiJv)

Comment: This doesnt give the expected result. You are returning Tag3, Tag10, Tag2 but Tag1 is in the requirements. It should technically return nothing. I want all 3 to be required. So if the tags are Tag1, Tag2, Tag3 it should return all products with all 3 of those tags.

Comment: @DevNinjaJeremy: Ah, then I misread your question. I thought you wanted only **any** of the tags. It can be easily modified.

Comment: @DevNinjaJeremy: I've updated the answer (and the demo).

Comment: This still doesnt work for me, but I did use this method to successfully get what I wanted. When i was searching for multiple tags it failed. What i did was instead of using the array_intersect i just looped through each array and compaired to each passed tag. if it matched i just kept a count. if all matched i collected the products information.

Comment: @DevNinjaJeremy: For which input(s), did this fail? If you don't mind, can you show a demo (on ideone.com) that reproduces this problem, so I fix my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to go with the regex i recommand some regex like

```
Tag2(,.*)?$|Tag1(,.*)?$/i
```

See live example [here](http://regex101.com/r/sE4rX7)

With new specifications you have to use positive lookahead

```
(?=(((Tag1|Tag2|Tag3)(,.*)?$)))
```

See live example [here](http://regex101.com/r/hD6jP2)

Comment: This doesnt give the expected result either. It will still match Tag1 or Tag2. I need Tag1 AND Tag2 to match.

Comment: However it seems to me you only need to know if this product matches any of the tags and if so you add the product to the list? Or is there something you are not telling us  ;)

Comment: I don't think the regex does what the OP wants. It should only match if all the tags occur in the comma-separated string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regular expression has 2 small details to consider.
1 - missing the first delimiter character /
2 - group in brackets the options you want to choose one of them

```
$regex = "/\b(" . $tag1 . "|" . $tag2 . "|" . $tag3 . ")\b/i";


try with this code to see my result.
<?php
 $tag1 = 'Tag1';
 $tag2 = 'Tag2';
 $tag3 = 'Tag3';

$arr = array();
$arr["#1-product-tags"] = "Tag3,Tag10,Tag2";
$arr["#2-product-tags"] = "Tag1,Tag3,Tag10";
$arr["#3-product-tags"] = "Tag5,Tag1,Tag3";
$arr["#4-product-tags"] = "Tag8,Tag4,Tag20";
$arr["#5-product-tags"] = "Tag20,Tag100,Tag500";
var_dump($arr);

//empty collection array to fill with product loop
$collection = array();

//dynamically generated regex
$regex = "/\b(" . $tag1 . "|" . $tag2 . "|" . $tag3 . ")\b/i";
var_dump($regex);

//loop through each product and throw matches to collection
foreach($arr as $product) {
    //var_dump($product);
    if(preg_match($regex,$product)) {
        array_push($collection,$product);
    }
}
var_dump($collection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive finally came up with a solution that worked. `/^(?=.*?Tag1)(?=.*?Tag2)(?=.*?Tag3).*$/` works like a charm